# Start one Runnable after another

Tags: java, android

I have got 2 runnables. What is the best wait to start one after another? For instance,

```
Rrunnable r = new Runnable(this,initialize); 
r.execute();
unzipTask rT = new unzipTask(this);
rT.execute();
```

Comment: what is a Rrunnable, and what does execute do ? (as it is not a method of the java interface Runnable)

Comment: I thought you understand the idea reding the name og the topic...

Comment: a Runnable is usually a java.lang interface, and it does not have an execute method. My comment was regarding what does execute actually do, since it looks like a method from `AsyncTask`, which is already executed on an executor, which is already a singlethreadexecutor since API 11. So while I get the idea of sequencial execution, the specifics are not entirely obvious from the title of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [single thread executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29), it guarantees that the `Runnable`'s you post to it will be executed sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put them into another thread:

```
private static Runnable combined(final Runnable r1, final Runnable r2) {
    if (r1== null) {
        return r2;
    }
    if (r2 == null) {
        return r1;
    }
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            r1.run();
            r2.run();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `join()` method to make one thread wait until the other has finished the execution.

More on `join()` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29).

Comment: Interesting but no example to use.

Comment: Here are the examples -> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_join.htm
http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-join-multiple-threads-in-java-example-tutorial.html